# Xamarin - Android - Activity not removed from activity stack on button click

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

I have a service that calls a Activity using the following code:

```
var activityIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(cptChamadaActivity));
                activityIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                StartActivity(activityIntent);
```

Inside the OnCreate method of the activity, I have that code:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Chamada);

        var simBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.simBtn);
        var naoBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.naoBtn);

        simBtn.Click += (sender, e) => { Finish(); };
        naoBtn.Click += (sender, e) => { Finish(); };
```

If I click on the **simBtn**, the Activity closes, but is not removed from the activity stack, but, if I put the Finish(); inside the OnCreate(), like that:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Chamada);

        var simBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.simBtn);
        var naoBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.naoBtn);

        simBtn.Click += (sender, e) => { Finish(); };
        naoBtn.Click += (sender, e) => { Finish(); };

        Finish();
```

the Activity is closed **and** removed from the stack.
I'm using the **NoHistory = true** on my Activity declaration.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you check if the Activity is still on the stack?

Comment: Hi Sven. On my device, it's done by holding the Home Button.

Comment: Ahhh ok. I thought you were talking about the actual view stack of an app instead of the open activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I've misunderstood the question. Now in your comment in the original question i think i do now.

The Activity is visible in activity stack on the device itself. I think it is added after OnResume because then all the views are inflated etc making it for Android possible to show it on the stack. If you use Finish(); in OnCreate the views are not visible yet thus not showing up on the stack.

Don't worry, if you finish your activity the activity is actually finished even if Android shows it to the user trough the stack. It's just a means for the user to return to your app.

You can confirm this by overriding OnDestroy and placing a breakpoint. If it's hit then you know the activity is closed. If not, then look at my original answer.

**Original answer:**

I've ran in the same kind of problem recently. I almost completed my app and during the testing phase other people noticed that Activities were not being disposed. As a result after hours of using the app, the app ran out of memory and hung.

The problem you have probably lies not in your OnCreate but in OnResume as you pass your Activity to another object that is keeping the reference to it thus the Activity not being disposed by mono GC. However without the code in OnResume i can't be 100% sure that you have the same problem i had.

The reason why your example is acting like you described is because when you call Finish(); within OnCreate, OnResume will never be called in the Android lifecycle(Just tested it). So the Activity leak has never occurred. If you use Finish(); within anonymous method then OnResume has already been ran and the code within has already created an Activity leak.

If you like more help with your code please post your OnResume code.

Some tips:

Try avoiding using this and thus passing Activity to other objects. If some object requires a Context, use ApplicationContext instead of this.

If really really need to pass the Activity to other object, create a WeakReference within the object:

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
   private WeakReference _weakactivity;
   private Activity _activity
   {
     get { return _weakactivity.Target as Activity; }
     set { _weakactivity = new WeakReference(value); }
   }

   public SomeClass(Activity activity)
   {
     _activity = activity;
   }
 }
```

The example will create a weak reference telling the GC it is allowed to dispose it when not used(My understanding of how it works, can be wrong.)

Also another tip is to use Action instead of EventHandlers. As you can use action = null; To discard all events. If you still want to use EventHandlers make sure you unsubscribe before OnDestroy is called.

For more info on this watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88ZLgLrwdts

Comment: Hi Danik, thanks for the answer. Actually, i did not override the OnResume() at all. I tried to unsubscribe the events before the base.OnDestroy gets called, but still not work.

Comment: Hi Danik, thanks again for the answer. I found the solution and posted it here. While your answer was not the actual solution for my problem, it was still helpfull, so I upvoted you. Thanks for your time and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it by creating a simple Activity that just finishes itself after the ***base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState)***, and then starting it from the actual Activity I want to close and then Finishing it.

Here is the Activity:

```
[Activity]
public class clsExitActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Finish();
    }

    public static void ExitApp(Context ctx)
    {
        var i = new Intent(ctx, typeof(clsExitActivity));
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ExcludeFromRecents | ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
        ctx.StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And then the usage (from the activity I want to close):

```
base.Finish();
clsExitActivity.ExitApp(ApplicationContext);
```

I found the code for the ***clsExitActivity*** in another question, but I can't find it again to paste it's URL here.